# Javascript Load Random Colour each time

Tags: javascript, colors

I am using js to generate a graph from a bootstrap template.

This graph shows a list of appointment types & values

```
try {
    //bar chart
    var ctx = document.getElementById("ReferralTypeWeekly");
    if (ctx) {
      ctx.height = 200;
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        defaultFontFamily: 'Poppins',
        data: {
          labels: ["Apt Type 1", "Apt Type 2", "Apt Type 3", "Apt Type 4", "Apt Type 5", "Apt Type 6", "Apt Type 7", "Apt Type 8", "Apt Type 9", "Apt Type 10", "Apt Type 11"],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Week 06",
              data: [7, 31, 47, 41, 10, 42, 3, 19, 16, 24, 0, 26],
              borderColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.9)",
              borderWidth: "0",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)",
              fontFamily: "Poppins"
            },
            {
              label: "Week 07",
              data: [10, 67, 112, 57, 21, 39, 9, 23, 30, 26, 9, 54],
              borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.09)",
              borderWidth: "0",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(123, 255, 0,0.5)",
              fontFamily: "Poppins"
            },
            {
              label: "Week 08",
              data: [4, 47, 93, 58, 21, 29, 6, 10, 32, 30, 6, 33],
              borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.09)",
              borderWidth: "0",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 123,0.5)",
              fontFamily: "Poppins"
            }
          ]
        },
        options: {
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
            labels: {
              fontFamily: 'Poppins'
            }

          },
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                fontFamily: "Poppins"

              }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                fontFamily: "Poppins"
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    }


  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

on the lines

```
borderColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.9)",
```

and

```
backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.5)",
```

I would like to have these randomly generated from a preset list, however as a unique colour for each set, but identical colors for the borderColor and backgroundColor for each value.

I searched around on here but don't even know where to begin here.

Some of my other graphs use multiple datasets (not just 2 like this example).

Looking forward to peoples suggestions on where I start

Cheers

UPDATE : HERE IS A PHOTO OF THE GRAPH
[image]

Comment: So do you want to have a list of colors and randomly select one or create a random color on the spot? And do they need to be unique?

Comment: @Aishwarya that's probably hard to do seeing how big the code already is. Creating a fiddle and linking it seems more appropriate.

Comment: @nickzoum i was thinking randomly selected from a predefined list. They need to be unique to stop 2 bars next to each other both using #333333 for example...

Ideally I would pop in a list of simple colours such as the basic color list from https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html

Comment: @nickzoum added a photo for reference

Comment: Will the predefined list also be randomly generated?

Comment: @nickzoum , no I can set this as a list... say

0,0,0;255,255,255;255,0,0;0,255,0;128,128,128;0,128,0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `splice` the array at a random index.

```js
var predefinedList = ["0,0,0", "255,255,255", "255,0,0", "0,255,0", "128,128,128", "0,128,0"];

function getRandomColor() {
  return predefinedList.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * predefinedList.length), 1)[0];
}

document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(getRandomColor());
});
```

```html
<button id="test">New Color</button>
```

If you want to add random values to `predefinedList` you can do (This can create up to 256 unique colors):

```js
var start = Date.now();

function fillArray(size, callBack) {
  return Array.apply(null, Array(size)).map(callBack);
}

function getIndex(val, index) {
  return index;
}

var r = fillArray(256, getIndex);
var g = fillArray(256, getIndex);
var b = fillArray(256, getIndex);

var predefinedList = fillArray(256, function() {
  return [r, g, b].map(function(color) {
    return color.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length), 1)[0];
  }).join(",");
});

console.log("Milliseconds elapsed: " + (Date.now() - start));

console.log(predefinedList);
```

You can combine both to get this:

```js
function fillArray(size, callBack) {
  return Array.apply(null, Array(size)).map(callBack);
}

function getIndex(val, index) {
  return index;
}

var r = fillArray(256, getIndex);
var g = fillArray(256, getIndex);
var b = fillArray(256, getIndex);

var predefinedList = fillArray(256, function() {
  return `rgb(${[r, g, b].map(function(color) {
    return color.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length), 1)[0];
  }).join(",")})`;
});


function getRandomColor() {
  return predefinedList.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * predefinedList.length), 1)[0];
}

var container = document.querySelector("#container");
var color = getRandomColor();

while (color){
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.setAttribute("style", `background-color: ${color};`);
  container.appendChild(newDiv);
  color = getRandomColor();
}
```

```css
#container>div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

You could also create the `r`,`b` and `g` arrays in the following way:

```js
function fillArray(size, callBack) {
  return Array.apply(null, Array(size)).map(callBack);
}

function createIndexFunction(start, multiplier) {
  return function(val, index) {
    return start + index * multiplier;
  }
}

var r = fillArray(26, createIndexFunction(0, 10));
// 26 (how many elements to create)
// 0 (start with r: 0 )
// 10 (skip 10 records r: 0, r: 10 ... r: 250)
var g = fillArray(26, createIndexFunction(200, 1));
// 26 (how many elements to create)
// 0 (start with g: 200 )
// 1 (don't skip any records)
var b = fillArray(26, createIndexFunction(50, 5));
// 26 (how many elements to create)
// 0 (start with b: 50 )
// 5 (skip 5 records b: 50, b: 55 ... b: 175)

console.log(r);
console.log(g);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Thanks, that top example pretty much smashes the question for me...

however now I have the task of embedding this in the original js :D

Man I wish I spent more time studying JS right now haha

Comment: Glad to help (you can accept+up-vote if you want), also are you sure you don't want to dynamically generate the array?

Comment: my issue with doing that is ensuring the colors are distinct enough - especially allowing for colorblind users so chosing colorblind friendly colours

Comment: @HenryAspden Fair enough, though you could just make less `rpg` values with bigger gaps between them or make the values go from `200` to `256` etc.

Comment: baby steps first haha... Combining the 2 so that it puts that RBG into the dataset field is hard enough as it is... haha. Any tips?

Comment: @HenryAspden Not sure what the problem is. Tips for doing what?

Comment: @HenryAspden It would be a lot easier to help if you were to create a new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and link it here.

Comment: oh so I come from a html & php background. My plan was to put your first code in a file called rgb-color-random.html with <script></script> tags around. modify it so that on loading it it returns the value... Scripts tags working great and getting that into my main.js file where the rest all loads, however I need to make your code load automatically on loading... Here is a .js fiddle - i am wanting the output to be just the rgb code e.g. "0,255,255"

https://jsfiddle.net/haspden/z6740jad/6/

Comment: @HenryAspden Isn't the output just `"0,255,255"` now? Also scripts load atomically when they get loaded.

Comment: I am wanting to output the value not to the console though but as raw text, so when I run this file https://jsfiddle.net/haspden/z6740jad/22/ the output in the bottom right output screen would be 0,255,255 - that way I could call it with a file_get_contents(); in php to get this value where I need it.

Comment: I feel like document.wite() might be the way to go about this?

Comment: @HenryAspden Wait, are you trying to get a value from JavaScript with PHP by reading the html? Why don't you just do an AJAX request, or just send the value as a parameter when you `get` or `post` the page

Comment: I'll cross those bridges another day I think. I admit that they would be better however for now a document.write would be quicker and easier for me in this scenario. Would you be able to help me with this please...

down the line I need to go back to basics with my Javascript & learn from the ground up again

Comment: sorted... will update my question with the solution based on your answer ASAP. Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: @HenryAspden I would reccomend using `document.body.appendChild` over `document.write`. Just create an element that you can locate from your PHP code and set its text.